# Propagating an event on superimposed div and svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have superimposed div tag on top of another div.  I want to propagate an event which occurred on a top div to the bottom div.  Setting "pointer-events:none" on the top layer allows the bottom layer to trigger an event but I do not want certain mouse events ignored on the top layer.  What are the solutions to accomplish the bottom layer div to trigger events which occurred on the top layer?

```
<div>
  <div id="top" class="layers"><span>top</span></div>
  <div id="bottom2" class="layers"><object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="100px" height="100px"></object></div>
</div>

<script>
var bottom2 = document.getElementById('bottom2');
  bottom2.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    console.log('mouseover bottom');
  });

var top = document.getElementById('top').addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
    console.log('mouseover top');
    bottom2.dispatchEvent(e);
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/katakuri/nwqhm1dn/5/

Thanks,

Comment: What event do you want to propagate?  mouseover?

Comment: I would like to see if "mouseover", "click", "mouseenter", "mouseout" would be the events I would like to pass on to the bottom layer.

Comment: Ok, so I did figure out passing events but I am not sure if there are better ways to do this.  http://jsfiddle.net/katakuri/nwqhm1dn/7/